# ethers.js block range is too wide

Tags: ethers.js

I encounter this error when I want to receive `Transfer` events.

This error occurs when there is no wallet installed on the browser

My code to receive events:

```
let events = await this.nft.queryFilter(this.nft.filters.Transfer());
```

Error:

```
index.ts:269  Uncaught (in promise) Error: processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"error\":{\"code\":-32600,\"message\":\"block range is too wide\"},\"id\":null}", error={"code":-32600}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_getLogs\",\"params\":[{\"fromBlock\":\"0x0\",\"toBlock\":\"latest\",\"address\":\"0x461e969311a58a02ec802ef2d231612868b0720a\",\"topics\":[\"0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef\"]}],\"id\":44,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="https://rpc.ankr.com/eth_sepolia/4aa2697e6bc9624f63a2a3faa5bc816b8ac0008e65a538d7b9ccde1d036297ee", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)
    at Logger.makeError (index.ts:269:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.ts:281:1)
    at eval (index.ts:341:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (index.ts:1:1)
```

Please give me a solution, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should give appropriate block range to queryFilter.

In your error message, the query search for your nft transfer event from block  0 to latest block.

```
"params\":[{\"fromBlock\":\"0x0\",\"toBlock\":\"latest\"
```

Instead, you can try below.

```
const latestBlockNum = await <provider>.getBlockNumber();
let events = await this.nft.queryFilter(this.nft.filters.Transfer(), latestBlockNum - 1000, latestBlockNum);
```